# Connectedness and compactness of a union of two sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let:
$$A=\Big\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: 0 \le x \le 1, y=\frac{x-1}{n},\, n\in \mathbb N \Big\}$$
$$B=\Big\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2: 0 \le x \le 1, y=\frac{x}{n},\, n\in \mathbb N \Big\}$$
Is $A \cup B$ connected? Is it compact?

At first sight the union of these sets looks to be connected but not compact, yet I struggle to prove it.

I tried to prove the connectedness by showing that $A \cup B$ cannot be divided into two open (closed), disjoint sets but I get lost when it comes down to making a rigid formula. Could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first deal with the compactness. Looking at certain points on the $x$-axis, we see that $A\cup B$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, hence it is not compact.

Regarding the connectedness, first note that both $A$ and $B$ are connected. If we had $A\cap B \neq \varnothing$, the connectedness of $A\cup B$ would follow from that. But $A\cap B = \varnothing$, so we need to argue differently. However, we can write

$$A\cup B = A_1 \cup B$$

with a connected $A_1 \supset A$ such that $A_1\cap B \neq \varnothing$. Then the general fact that the union of two connected sets with nonempty intersection is connected finishes the proof.

To find such an $A_1$, remember that if $E$ is connected, and $E \subset F \subset \overline{E}$, then $F$ is connected too.

> So one should look at $\overline{A}\cap B$.

Comment: $Cl(A) \cap B = \{ (0,0)\}$, but what is the $A_1$ we want to find, and why can we denote the equailty like that?

Comment: We want $A_1 \supset A$, $A_1 \cap B \neq \varnothing$, $A_1 \subset A\cup B$, and $A_1$ shall be connected. Looking at the last line before the spoiler, can you guess what $A_1$ should be?

Comment: Not really - it could be either $Cl(A)$ - which is not a subset of $A \cup B$ or $A\cup \ one \ line\  from \ B \ or \{(0,0)\}$

Comment: There are of course many possible choices, but the setup I gave was for $A \subset A_1 \subset \overline{A}$. Together with the aim that $A_1 \cap B \neq \varnothing$ and $A_1 \subset A\cup B$, that determines $A_1$. You could also use $A \cup\text{ one line from }B$, but then you'd have the same problem of showing connectedness.

Answer (score 0):

A set is connected if and only if any continuous function mapping from this set to $\{0,1\}$ is a constant function. Since both $A, B$ are union of closed segments and connected at the point $(1,0)$ and $(0,0)$ respectively, a continuous function $f:A\cup B \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ must be constant on the two parts. By continuity, $f((0, -1/n))\rightarrow f((0,0))$ hence $f$ is constant on $A\cup B$.